# I wanted to upload a zipped build folder to my linux machine and unzip and deploy

Tags: python, file-upload, ftp

I wanted to upload a zipped build folder to my linux machine and unzip and deploy.. My issue here is the zip file itself 400MB takes 2 hour to upload, is there any way, I can compress file more to reduce like 100MB or some and upload? Anyother help also welcome.. Am doing it with Jenkins and python

I tried to make it as tar or gzip which results same size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing which can magically compress 400 MB to 100 MB, especially not if these are already compressed data like (usually) when you have a ZIP file.

How much data can be compressed depends very much on the data - for normal text 50% is not unusual but for binary data it is much less. And it usually will not be able to compress already compressed data any further - otherwise you could just compress again and again until you only have a single byte.

> I tried to make it as tar or gzip which results same size

This is expected. While different compression algorithms might slightly differ in the compression they can achieve these differences are only in a few percent and not in the several factors you need here. Lossless compression is essentially compacting information and data can only be compacted up to some size since the original information somehow needed to by retained. This is different to compression of images or audio where loss of information is often acceptable (and results in loss of quality) and thus much higher compression factors are possible.

Answer (score -2):

you can use Uharch programm to compress your file

Comment: Just using a different compression program does not change the achievable lossless compression by multiple factors as would be needed here (i.e. to reach the goal of 100 MB compressed data instead of 400 MB compressed data).